# Cancel one of multi selection when sortable two table jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've developed feature sortable beetween two table using jquery. Following this url:   `jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/shLQE/`

When dragging the item article #1, article #2 from available to my articles. I just wanna article#1 dropped in My articles and article #2 revert back to available area. I've try that but not done. Can anybody help me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/shLQE/245/), also posting runnable code here:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.droptrue').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
  var lastItem;
  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.droptrue',
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: true,
    helper: function(e, item) {
      if (!item.hasClass('selected'))
        item.addClass('selected');
      var elements = $('.selected').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').clone();
      var helper = $('<ul/>');
      item.siblings('.selected').addClass('hidden');
      return helper.append(elements);
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var elements = ui.item.siblings('.selected.hidden').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
      ui.item.data('items', elements);
    },
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.before(ui.item.data('items'));
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.siblings('.selected').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      revertArticle();
    },
    update: updatePostOrder
  });

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").css('minHeight', $("#sortable1").height() + "px");
  updatePostOrder();
});

function revertArticle() {
  var widget = $("#sortable2").sortable("widget");
  var matchedItems = $.grep(widget[0].children, function(item) {
    return (item.id == "article_1" || item.id == "article_2")
  });
  if ($(matchedItems).length > 1) {
    $("#sortable1").append($.grep(widget[0].children, function(item) {
      return (item.id == "article_1")
    }));
    $("#sortable1").sortable('refresh');
    updatePostOrder();
  }
}
var arr = [];

function updatePostOrder() {
  arr = [];
  $("#sortable2 li").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $('#postOrder').val(arr.join(','));
}
```

```css
.listBlock {
  float: left;
}
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  color: black;
  cursor: move;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 250px;
  background: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="maincontainer">
  <div id="navtoplistline">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="maincolumn">
      <div class="text">
        <hr />
        <div class="listBlock">
          <h2>Available</h2>

          <ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
            <li id="article_1">Article #1</li>
            <li id="article_2">Article #2</li>
            <li id="article_3">Article #3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="listBlock">
          <h2>My Articles</h2>

          <ul id="sortable2" class='droptrue'>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <br clear="both" />
        <p>Which articles, in which order?:
          <br />
          <input type="text" id="postOrder" name="postOrder" value="" size="30" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've ran code which you just refactored. but article #2 not shown in my articles area. Can you fix this?

Comment: can you please elaborate, what you're expecting? I think I've misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: I mean. When drag article #1 and article #2  to 'my articles',  article #1 will revert old state (back to area state) and article #2 will be shown at 'my articles'.

Comment: I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/shLQE/245/) and the code snippet. please check and let me know.

Comment: That's so great. Thanks you so much.